# Angular ui modal unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a modal from angular ui bootstrap. After I implemented it on my web application, I got an unexpected behavior which is the modal does show up after I clicked the text, but what shows up is not the path that I wanted but rather the navbar of the web app.

Here's the code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <base href='/'> 
    <!-- load bootstrap from CDN and custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- load angular and angular-route via CDN -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>



</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>Testing App</a>
                </div>  

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="ModalController">
                    <li><a href="#" ng-click="open('lg')">Write</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])

    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'

            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  
    });
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('MyApp')

    .controller('HomeController', function($scope, $location) {

        $scope.data = "Hello Angular";
    })



    .controller('ModalController', function($scope, $location, $modal, $log) {

        $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

        $scope.open = function (size) {

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                controller: function() {


                },
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    items: function () {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            }, function () {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };
    });
```

home.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Awesome {{ data }}</h1>

</div>
```

modal.html (The path that the modal suppose to show);

```
<h1>Need to show this actually</h1>
```

The picture, what shows up after i clicked the text that trigger the modal event

[image]

Comment: your modal.html contains only `<h1>' tag..where is modal structured html take a look here http://plnkr.co/edit/hsqTA72AgIIJy9mI3fSZ?p=preview

Comment: No matter what i put in modal.html , the result will still be the same, the reason , why I put only <h1> tag in the example is to simplify things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
<h1>Need to show this actually</h1>
</script>
```

right after

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="ModalController">
```

and it works in plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bPuemujbTiX7U8AnY607?p=preview

Comment: edited my answer: please try to load template inside ModalController-controlled html

Comment: appreciate your help but the problem still persist, as any other examples that I have come across so far , you don't need to implicitly add the ng-template right after the ng-controller since the ModalController itself handles the path.

Comment: Hello sinusGob, does it work for you with addition above, rather than external html?

Comment: And here is another plunker, with external html template: [link](//plnkr.co/edit/AqkAcaIO4TK4l252W9H0?p=preview)

Comment: So if it works only in plunkers, could it be you need to alter $routeProvider?

Comment: Sorry, in fact it works well, even with $routeProvider in a plunker. Turns out I could not manage to reproduce your error: 1st time I feel frustrated not to be able to get errors!?